# Facebook Open Graph, can I upload a User Generated Photo (as opposed to sending a URL)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've read the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/).

I have an action, "cook", which is applied to an object "recipe". I want to allow the user to post a photo of their cooking when they perform the action.

I would like to have the photo hosted on Facebook. Is there any way to post the actual image data as part of the request, rather than posting a URL to the user generated photo?

The docs say

> The photo used will NOT be taken from the object's meta data og:image tag. Instead, it is passed with the POST

and

> The photo will be uploaded and placed in a Facebook photo album titled after the "App Display Name" for that app

but they also mention that the `image[0][url]` property is required.

The context is an iOS app: the user takes a photo on the device and wishes to post it to Facebook. To get a URL to the image, I'd obviously have to do an upload to some web hosting somewhere as a separate step, which would be harder to code and would require some hosting.

Comment: you mean ,,do you want to upload photo?

Comment: I want to upload a photo as part of an Open Graph action, specifically tagging it as a User Generated Photo as mentioned in that documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but they also mention that the image[0][url] property is required.

You’ll have to upload the photo first to some place where it’s available over the web via HTTP, and then give that URL while posting your action.

Comment: Is that the only thing you can do? Is there really no way to upload an image to Facebook as part of an action?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but unfortunately that's the only way to do it. I've spoken with a Facebook engineer at a meet up last week and he confirmed that at the moment you can't send the picture when you post the action. It has to be available somewhere on the web.

Comment: It is now possible to upload images as part of an action. For more details on the iOS API see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest/#requestForUploadStagingResourceWithImage%3A

Comment: could you tell javascript equivalent of image[0][url] ?